# Teamviewer 10 service hung on starting, slows down startup

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, freeze, teamviewer

Suddenly my PC started taking a long time to boot. I have windows 8.1 on an SSD so it's usually pretty fast, like 20 or 30s from pressing the button to desktop, most of it is the motherboard stuff. Now it gets to the desktop making good time, but it just hangs there, with most of the shortcuts without icons (as in white files), not opening the programs that are set to start with windows and it won't let me open the task manager. I can open other programs with no lag at all, like firefox or matlab. After a couple minutes it snaps out of it and the startup resumes, the taskmanager finally opens, the icons load and Avast and that stuff continue starting.

The event viewer had this error about team viewer service hangin at startup:

```
The TeamViewer 10 service hung on starting.
```

The whole log is in here: http://pastebin.com/Rrj0t44X

I tried disabling TeamViewer and the computer effectively starts up normally. I tried reinstalling TeamViewer and the problem persisted.

Does anyone have any idea as to what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Try to install an old version , 9 for example, test it then try to upgrade to 10.It might be a bug in ver 10.

Comment: I also have this problem, thanks for posting. I've been pulling my hair all day long trying to understand what was happening. I initially thought it was a driver conflict. My problem started this same week and Windows (8.1) installed only these three updates: - KB3048778
- KB3035583
- KB2976978 Teamviwer version : 10.0.40642 PS: This problem affects both host-only version and the full client. I opened a ticked with teamviewer (I don't know if they respond to non-commercial users)

Answer (score 2):

Go to Computer Management\Services and change the TeamViewer service from Automatic to Automatic (Delayed Start).

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a complete uninstall before reinstalling Teamviewer?
Also check your registry to confirm that all traces of Teamviewer have been removed - it's possible that some remnant of the service registration is still present. 
Reboot and confirm normal boot.
Reinstall and test if okay.
Service Control manager will by default wait up to 2 minutes for a service to start before deciding that it can't be started - this would most likely explain the delay before the GUI components and Task Manager become available.

Comment: I did uninstall completely and used CCleaner to clean the registry. However it kept happening. I rolled back to version 9 and that solved the problem, so apparently it's a bug in version 10.